# lock answer on webform once selected

Tags: webforms

ON Drupal 7

I am trying to figure out how to lock an answer in a Drupal Webform answers the questions. (once the person filling out the webform) It is a quiz to enter into a contest. Only one question with 2 options.If they answer right they are entered into a contest, if not than they are not entered.

For example when filling out the webform: If there is a question that says- Do you like blue? the options are Yes or No. I want to have it so that once if the person selected No, than they cannot go back and answer Yes.

No turning back once answered...

Is that possible?

Comment: What if they made an error in their selection?

Comment: You can probably use some custom JavaScript to disable an element onblur.

Which version of the webform module are you using?  7 or 8

Comment: It is a quiz to enter into a contest. Only one question with 2 options.If they answer right they are entered into a contest. If not than they are not.

Comment: This is for version 7 of Drupal